# All users from Tableau using API

Tags: python-2.7, tableau-api

I am currently using Tableau server client python api to get list of users from the server. I am not a tableau server admin.

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

 server = TSC.Server('http://SERVERURL')

  all_groups, pagination_item = server.groups.get()
  mygroup = all_groups[1]


  pagination_item = server.groups.populate_users(mygroup)



  for user in mygroup.users :
        print(user.name)
```

The above code will list only first 100 users. How to get list of all users from a particular group in Tableau

Comment: Does the API have a limit on how many items can be pulled at once?

Comment: https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/docs/docs/api-ref.md

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question, that’s just the API wrapper. Does the API _itself_ limit the received resources?

Comment: I was going through the documentation. I think its related to the pagination. Default they have given is 100. Max is 1000. Under "Get Users in Group" in below link : http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_concepts_paging.htm

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
You just need to provide 
request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
and use it like this:
pagination_item = server.groups.populate_users(mygroup, req_options=request_options))